# NameError in PostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

I have used 4 important gems

```
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan', '~> 2.0' 
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.4'
```

I have 2 main Controller **"User" and "Post"** and registered in active_admin(rails generate active_admin:resource User and rails generate active_admin:resource Post).I have used **cancancan** for the authorization.
I have defined the ability in

#### ability.rb

```
    if user.admin?  
        can :manage, :all
    else
        can :read, Posts
    end
```

#### ApplicationController.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
      format.html { redirect_to main_app.root_url, notice: exception.message }
      format.js   { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
    end
  end
    def current_ability
      @current_ability ||= AccountAbility.new(current_admin_user)
    end
end
```

#### schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_02_14_200911) do

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "admin", default: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "published_at"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_posts_on_category_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_posts_on_slug", unique: true
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_users_on_slug", unique: true
  end

end
```

### Goal

My goal is: 1. Only Admin can post,add user, add category basically manage all.
2. guest User can only read.
So I used cancancan gem to do authorization. But I am getting error:

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::AccountAbility
Extracted source (around line #12):
  end
    def current_ability
      @current_ability ||= AccountAbility.new(current_admin_user)
    end
end
```

And I have uploaded on [git](https://github.com/Pushpamk/web/tree/master/Kumarpushpam.com) if you need any further information.
It will be great if you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NameError is because your model is named `Ability`, not `AccountAbility`, so change your `current_ability` method to:

```
def current_ability
  @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_admin_user)
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I did't notice :'(

Comment: actually Still I am not able to achieve my goals. I defined the ability as shown in ability.rb, but still guest user is able to create, edit and delete the Post.